# go-swagger TLS Config

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2, go-swagger

I generated a golang server with go-swagger.   I set the scheme to https (and only https).   When I startup my server I get a TLS error.

```
the required flags `--tls-certificate` and `--tls-key` were not specified
```

It is clear that I haven't properly set my TLS flags but I really don't know the best way to to do this in go with go-swagger.

Anyone have any experience setting up TLS with go-swagger as I couldn't find any good links?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get certificates you get a private key file and a public key (certificate) file.

Here's an example of how they are used: https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/master/examples/todo-list#run-full-server

`./todo-list-server --tls-certificate mycert1.crt --tls-key mycert1.key`

Comment: Thank you, you were right.  It was getting lost when I built my docker file.  I set it in my build and passed it in.   Worked great.